The sign of the partial derivatives are independent of their component, and an extreme point exists, implies a constant function
Let $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ be a differentiable function, such that the sign of the partial derivative of $x_i$ is independent of $x_i$. It is also given that f has an extreme point that is not on its boundary.
This should imply that the function is constant; say we have some extreme point. Then the partial derivatives are all zero, and we can move along every axis without changing the function's value.
Is this a known theorem? what is its name/reference?

This is not that difficult to prove. I doubt that it has a specific name.
